# How To Pass Arrays From A String Array in One Struct To Titles In Array Of Buttons In A Class Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uibutton

I am new to coding and for my first app  I am trying to create a struct which stores arrays of strings which can be loaded into my UIButton Array to be set as their individual titles. I created the struct called ToDo to try to follow the MVC structure in my app. I attempted to create an array of strings in my struct called labelArray and a function that returns the string of the item in the array when it is called in my view controller called getLabelArray which I want to accept an integer of the index count into an array of UI Buttons. The goal I want to achieve is setting the placeholder titles for my buttons from an array before the view loads. Any help is welcome! I have attached my code with comments. Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//Instantiates ToDo Class Object

var labelArray = ToDo()

//Main Score Label

@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

//Array of TodoItems To Be Filled By ToDo Class

@IBOutlet var toDoItemArray: [UIButton]!

//Array of Scores To Be Filled By ToDo Class

@IBOutlet var scoreArray: [UILabel]!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     /* For every item in toDoItemArray will set text of each UIButton label to a 
     string in labelArray from ToDo struct */   

   for i in 0...toDoItemArray.count {
                        func updateTextInArray(){
                            toDoItemArray[i].setTitle("\(labelArray.getLabelArray(index: i))", for: UIControl.State.normal)

            }

        }

    }
}





// ToDoStruct

import Foundation
    struct ToDo {

    var task1 = "Cooking"
    var task2 = "Cleaning"
    var task3 = "Walking Dog"

    lazy var labelArray = [task1,task2,task3]

    mutating func getLabelArray (index: Int) -> String {

    return labelArray[index]

    }
```

Comment: So this is all over the place and I'm still not sure what you're attempting to do. Are you trying to set an array of strings to an array of buttons on their text label?

Answer (score 0):

The following properly sets the titles of the UIButtons.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0..<toDoItemArray.count {
        toDoItemArray[i].setTitle(
            "\(labelArray.getLabelArray(index: i))",
            for: .normal
        )
    }
}
```

However, you really don't need the unnecessary `getLabelArray`.
If you want `labelArray` to be a read-only property, use the `private(set)` keyword:

```swift
private(set) lazy var labelArray = [task1, task2, task3]
```

Also, with renaming `var toDo = ToDo()`, you can tidy the `for` loop:

```swift
for (i, label) in toDo.labelArray.enumerated() {
    toDoItemArray[i].setTitle("\(label)", for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Hi Jay Lee! 
   Thank you for your prompt response! I see I forgot that the loop acts as a function and doesn’t need an inner function within the loop. I am currently facing follow up problems....

Comment: Can you explain what the follow up problems are?

Comment: Hi Jay, I am trying to move all of my list items from my array in my ToDo struct to my button labels in my array on view controller on load. I am confused how I can provide values before the app loads, as they need to be inserted upon the app opening.